# How can I delete completely duplicate rows from a query, without having a unique value for it?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I'm having an issue getting information from an MS Access Database table. I need a count of a code but I don't have to take into account duplicate rows, which means that I need to delete all duplicate rows.

Here's an example to illustrate what I need:

```
Code | Name 

12 | George
20  | John 
12 | George 
33 | John
```

I will need first to delete both rows with the same code, and then I need a count for the name the rest of the table data for example this will be the result that I'm expecting:

```
Name | Count

John | 2
```

I already have a query that does that for me, but is taking around 1 hour to get me around 5000 rows and I need something more efficient. My query:

```
  select name, count(*) from Table
  where name = '" + input_name + "'
    and code in (select code from Table group by code
                 having count(code) = 1)
  group by name
  order by count(name) desc;
```

I would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Usually done by using `DISTINCT`. Or is there a reason for you to avoid that?

Comment: The reason why I can't use it is that I need to delete completely multiple rows, DISTINCT keeps a unique value for duplicates.

Comment: And where's the Excel part in all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `in`, I might suggest filtering the original dataset in a subquery, e.g.:

```
select u.name, count(*)
from (select t.code, t.name from yourtable t group by t.code, t.name having count(*) = 1) u
group by u.name
```

Here, change `yourtable` to the name of your table.

Comment: I have already tried something like this but I'm getting an error that says " Run-time error '-21472117904 (80040e10)': No value given for one or more required parameters". I'm not clear if maybe the reason that the code is always changing might affect this solution.

Comment: Are you receiving that error using the code I posted?

Comment: Correct, I used the query you suggested

Comment: Actually I tried your solution again, and it worked! Thanks a lot! It seems that maybe I miss typed something last time.